# On macOS, is it possible to reserve input from an HID for a python program?

Tags: macos, barcode-scanner, pyusb

I want to give exclusive access to the input coming from a LASER barcode (point and trigger type) reader to a Python 3.6 program; that is, no other program should get input from the reader, regardless of UI focus (because the python program has already claimed the device for itself only.)

I've been able to this just fine on a Linux machine using Python 3.6 and pyusb library, but I can't replicate the funcionality in macOS, I get an error stating that I have insufficient permissions.

This actually happens in Linux too but it is easily worked-around by adding the current user to `dialout` group and creating udev rules file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb.rules` granting permissions to a user or group with this rule:

```sh
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0666"
```

**How can equivalent permissions be granted on macOS?**

Example code does exatcly what I want on Linux, but fails completely on macOS:

```py
import usb.core
import usb.util
device = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0519, idProduct=0x2017)
if device.is_kernel_driver_active(0):
    device.detach_kernel_driver(0)
    print("Kernel driver detached")
else:
    print("Kernel driver already detached")
try:
    device.set_configuration()
    device.reset()
    usb.util.claim_interface(device, 0) # error happens here
    print("Claimed device")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error when claiming device", e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

From what I've found on the Web, It doesn't seem like macOS has an equivalent mechanism to grant this access.

Error on macOS:

```sh
[Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

Comment: And if you run with `sudo YourScript` ?

Comment: Since it is an HID device, it is necessary to take measures related to the kernel, and if it is changed to a serial port device, will it automatically become an exclusive use device?

Comment: I forgot to mention this will have to run as a service that people won't have direct access to, so sudoing or running as root is not really an option.

Comment: @kunif how can it be turned from an HID to a serial port device? I'm willing to try different approaches to access the reader, just need some more pointers.

Comment: @Jonathan Acosta, For most scanners, setting barcode for mode change is written in the user manual etc. Please use it to change from keyboard input mode to serial port mode.

Comment: I think my scanner doesn't support that mode, I read the manual cover to cover and just found a whole bunch of configs to enable and disable barcode-related stuff :-S

Comment: @Jonathan Acosta, In that case, you could either create an exclusive control program that you think or switch to a scanner that supports serial port mode.

Comment: I contacted the manufacturer and they confirmed that my scanner doesn't support the mode we're talking about. They said a higher tier model, which is Blue Tooth, supports a mode called *SPP* but I'm not sure if that would solve my requirements.

Comment: @Jonathan Acosta, Since SPP is Serial Port Protocol (or Profile), I think that it can be used. However, since bluetooth is wireless, it is necessary to pay attention to the connection state and battery charge state.

Comment: Thanks @kunif. The model I''ve been using is actually wireless too, just not bluetooth. Again, thanks a lot for yout help! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've learned since this question was originally posted, you *can* reserve input from any USB device, as long as it supports "serial mode", if your device can be switched to this mode then the OS can treat it differently from the default HID mode, and you'll be able to grab it's input, even exclusively.

Disclaimer:

I havent' had a chance to fully test this as of posting this answer. Just wanted to give a quick update to any one interested.